# Switch with static argument (c#,WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, static, prism

I'm working on an application that contain 2 pages (main page, detail page)

The main page contain multiple buttons , what i want to do is to make the detail page aware of what button clicked so it gives the proper details.

What i did is declare a static variable and access to it from the main page

```
    private void NavigateToDetails(int ButtonNumber)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "DetailsPage");
        DetailsPageViewModel.CurrentPage = ButtonNumber;
    }

- On Detail page :

    private static int _currentPage;
    public static int CurrentPage
    {
        get { return _currentPage; }
        set
        {
            _currentPage = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged("CurrentPage");
        }
    }
```

if i bind this static variable to label it works but if i use it on a method it return 0 everytime , here is what i want it to do :

```
    private void ValuesRefreshed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (_currentPage)
        {
            case 1:
                Name = ModelDb1.Name
                break;
            case 2:
                Name = ModelDb2.Name
                break;
            default:
                Name = "not found"
                break;
        }
    }
```

---

## Solved

Update I just realized that I call the page before modifying the static so all I had to is to rewrite the NavigateToDetails to

```
DetailsPageViewModel.CurrentPage = ButtonNumber;            
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "DetailsPage");
```

Comment: how do you bind the static property in the xaml?

Comment: @ImadBoucetta, from where and in which moment `ValuesRefreshed` is invoked? Does it happen after DetailsPageViewModel.CurrentPage changes? please show that code too

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use static stuff unless you must. Inject a service (registered as singleton), and store your information there.